# Trying to add data to a pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

Say I want to add data to a pyplot. Okay so I have a pyplot with the x axis having data1, data2, data3 and the y axis having data1, data2, data3. It has a colourbar ranging from 0-1. Now say I want to plot data, e.g. data1,data1 share a score of 0.6. How would I plot this so the correct colour shows on the plot? Thanks
BTW i know you can add data via csv but i dont want to, i just want to add data myself using this program ive made.

this is the code i have so faR:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(10,10)
heat_map = sb.heatmap(data)

plt.show()
```

Comment: provide with some code so we can help you, maybe your data or something

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please read [How do I ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then post here your current code that includes a sample input, your desired output, and how the current output differs from the desired output. However, given your description, I am sure, you will find an adaptable example [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/index.html) or [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/04_plotting.html).

Comment: added code can anyone help now?